# creating attributes in sysfs

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, kernel-module

I am just trying to add a simple attribute to a device in the /sys filesystem.  Seemed pretty straightforward but none of the helper methods mentioned [here](http://delcom.sourceforge.net/sysfs.txt) or [here](http://book.chinaunix.net/special/ebook/Linux_Kernel_Development/0672327201/ch17lev1sec8.html) are exported from the kernel so I can't use them from a module?  I must be missing something, can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: IOCTL is looking better and better...

Answer (score 1):

> none of the helper methods mentioned here or here are exported from the kernel

They certainly are, grepping two out of the tree:

`fs/sysfs/file.c:EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(sysfs_create_file);`
`lib/kobject.c:EXPORT_SYMBOL(kobject_add);`